# PHP data type resource()

Tags: php, types

as we all know,there is a data type 'resouce' in php!I sometimes can encounter this data type!but I have some problems about this type!
when I have a db connect,I print the data type,it displays"resource(4, mysql link)",
when I create a image,I print the data type,it displays "resource(2, gd)"
i want to know what the number eg.'4','2' means in the "()".
sorry for my bad englis!

Comment: it means your echoing the wrong variable. but with out code ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you see `resource(4, ...)` what that means is that PHP is keeping a reference to a more complex object that isn't a normal PHP object, and thus can't be manipulated directly. It's typically used by libraries that interface with non-PHP code (such as database client libraries and the GD library).

The number is simply the ID number of that particular external object.

These resources are managed by the external library and only really given to PHP as an indirect reference; they only have meaning to the library code that created them.

Comment: Thank you!you descript it clearly!